# What is meant by parent process in unix

Tags: linux, unix

The parent process id of a unix PID is defined as:
Parent process ID (the ID of the process that started it).

What does this mena? e.g. I log in to the unix server and invoke a java process, the PID will be the ID of teh java process, but what is the parent process of the java process?

Comment: Try running the command `pstree` to see a tree with parent/child relationships.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be your shell's PID. The intuition is relatively simple if you understand [how a shell works](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) and what the [fork()](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28operating_system%29) system call does. To verify, run `java MyJavaProgram & ps -f`

A parent process is a process that spawns another one usually to do some work on its behalf(this is what a shell is). It is simply an application (typically written in C) that will execute the fork() command to spawn off a child process, send some work for it to do, and either wait for it to finish or accept other commands (i.e. if the `&` option is passed).